# Logging in with google account credentials?

Tags: 12.04, login, google

I's it possible to login with google account credentials like in ChromeOS from `gdm`?

If so, how?

Comment: good question but I don't think this is a happen thing. Google and ChromeOS go hand in hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short of setting your username as your google account name and your password as your google account password (which doesn't do anything really but make it more convenient to remember verything) I'd say no.